# Correct Syntax For Anonymous Function

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

The first of the following two functions, fn-apply-cmp-vals, returns a partial function that is used in the second function, apply-cmp-vals.

What is the correct syntax to embed fn-apply-cmp-vals as an anonymous function in apply-cmp-vals?

```
(defn fn-apply-cmp-vals
    [fn cmp-sos cmp-idx]
    (partial fn cmp-sos cmp-idx))

(defn apply-cmp-vals
    [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
    (let [fn-cmp (fn-apply-cmp-vals ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)]
        (map #(fn-cmp %1) cmp-vals)))
```

Specifically, I want to replace `fn-apply-cmp-vals ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)` with an anonymous function instead of a function call.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a look at this, in detail, one step at a time.

Your goal is to inline `fn-apply-cmp-vals` as an anonymous function in `apply-cmp-vals`. So lets do that first. Here is what your function looks like with no other changes:

```
(defn apply-cmp-vals
  [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
  (let [fn-cmp ((fn [f cmp-sos cmp-idx] (partial f cmp-sos cmp-idx))
                  ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)]
    (map #(fn-cmp %1) cmp-vals)))
```

This accomplishes your goal, but there is room for improvement. Since your function simply calls `partial` with the given arguments, lets replace the anonymous function with a direct call to `partial` with the correct arguments. This works because `partial` returns a partially applied function.

```
(defn apply-cmp-vals
  [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
  (let [fn-cmp (partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)]
    (map #(fn-cmp %1) cmp-vals)))
```

Now, lets look where `fn-cmp` is used. It is being called in its own anonymous function with a single argument. Since your partial function satisfies this requirement, you could instead just pass `fn-cmp` into the map function directly.

```
(defn apply-cmp-vals
  [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
  (let [fn-cmp (partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)]
    (map fn-cmp cmp-vals)))
```

Finally, if you desire, you can completely remove the `let` form:

```
(defn apply-cmp-vals
  [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
  (map (partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx) cmp-vals)))
```

So it turns out you didn't need an anonymous function at all!

Comment: Thanks. I'll go check this out.

Comment: You can also directly map `(partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)` instead of `#(ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx %1)` in the last solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
(defn apply-cmp-vals
  [cmp-vec cmp-vals cmp-vec-idx]
    (let [fn-cmp (partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)]
      (map fn-cmp cmp-vals)))
```

`fn-apply-cmp-vals` wasn't doing anything other than passing its arguments to `partial`.

`(partial ret-non-match-rows cmp-vec cmp-vec-idx)` will return an anonymous function.

`fn-cmp` is a function, so replace `(map #(fn-cmp %1) cmp-vals)` with `(map fn-cmp com-vals)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot partial itself returns a function.